# find the smallest integer value 1 such that no subset of elements

Tags: java

Having a hard time understanding what this question is asking me to do. I'm not asking for any code, I would just like an explanation of what this problem is asking and maybe how to attack it. Given a sorted array of positive integers, find the smallest integer value, x being greater or equal to 1 such that no subset of elements from the array sums to x. The array is sorted in non-decreasing order and could contain duplicates.For example, input{1,1,1,1,2) output 7, input{3,4,5} output 1, input{1,3,9} output 2.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would go through input aray, let's see (1,1,1,1,2) i take 1. No number is smaller than 1 that could be an output. Let's take next number in input. 1.i checked it already, try to add it to previous one. Resulting in 2. Output can be 1?no, we said it before. Next element from input is 1. Adding it to previous one gives2, I checked that. Add it to the first element in input. We have 3. But numbers smaller than 3 and bigger than 0 can not be output. Next number in input is 1, for it it is analogical. Next input number is 2. If we recursively try to sum it with previous results, we get to sum 6. Then 7 is smallest number that we can not get by summing any elements in input array. I mean, if you ty to sumany numbers in input, and any count oof them, and write the sums to the paper and sort it, then you try to find smallest number x that is not in the result list

Answer (score 0):

looks like a simple problem. You're basically solving for X. A number that lies between 1 and sum of all array values + 1

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2] > sum = 6
[3, 4, 5] > sum = 12
[1, 3, 9] > sum = 13
```

The criteria being that X cannot be a number within the array or a sum of any of the numbers contained within the array.

---

Simplest way to explain this problem is: "Given the numbers of an array, what is the smallest number ***NOT*** contained within the array that you ***CAN'T*** make by addition."

---

Take the first array. 7 is the output because, given the values of the array you can get the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 but not 7 by adding any / all numbers of the array.

Take the second array. 1 is the output because you can get the numbers 3, 7, 8, 9..this one is simple. The smallest number in the array is > than 1...so the answer is 1.

Take the third array. 2 is the output because you can get the numbers 1, 3, 4, 10, 12, 13. 1 and 3 exist..but not 2.

---

Maybe a good algorithm consists of creating a sorted set of all possible summations, given any array of integers. The answer to the problem being either 1, if the first number in the set is > than 1 or set[n] + 1 where set[n] = 1

Comment: I understood everything you said, except the last part "Maybe a good algorithm consists of creating a sorted set of all possible summations, given any array of integers. The answer to the problem being either 1, if the first number in the set is > than 1 or set[n] + 1 where set[n] = 1". Also I need to solve it in order O(n), any ideas how to go about that?